# Does this sentence need an additional comma?

Tags: commas

Does this sentence need an additional comma before the "I"?...

> As an award winning Producer, Director, Videographer and Video Editor I will manage and produce your next video project.

Comment: Yes it does.  Furthermore, I would hyphenate "award-winning".

Comment: And furthermore, none of the descriptors ("Producer", etc.) requires a capital letter.

Comment: the next question is of course do you need a comma before _and video editor_ ;) http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/052709serialcomma.htm

Comment: Thank you again...  If you would like you can see the link below for the result. http://www.goliath2.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [ell.se]

Comment: Writing advice is off topic here, but I see I'm closing the doors after the horse has bolted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. The words from ‘As’ to Editor’ are a separate grammatical unit, and a comma would make this clear. Apart from anything else, ‘Editor I’ looks as though there may be an Editor II and an Editor III.